# How is this called: projecting H over subspace

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Let's say I have some hamiltonian $H = H_A + H_B + H_I$ which describes a system composed of two parts $A$ ($B$), described by $H_A$ ($H_B$) and their interaction hamiltonian $H_I$.

To begin with I am interested in the ground state of said hamiltonian and I know that the energy scale of $B$ is way bigger than in $A$ so I start by doing an aproximation similar to the BO approximation. If ${|a_i>}$ and ${|b_i>}$ are some basis over $A$ and $B$ and $i=0$ corresponds to the ground state I can write based on my approximation the following:

"ground state of H" = $\sum_j c_j|a_j>|b_0>$

I intuitively belive I can reduce the dimensions of my space since I am only working with the ground state of $B$ and not the whole $B$, I should be able to define some kind of effective hamiltonian $H'$ such that

$$<a_i|<b_0|H|a_j>|b_0> = <a_i|H'|a_j>$$

I don't know how to refer to this technique, it's kind of similar to a partial trace but not quite the same I belive.

I am inclined to define $H'$ as $H' = <b_0|H|b_0>$ but I don't like this very much since its not quite well defined.

How should I call this operation? Thank you very much